# java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, network-programming

I'm installing CSVN using *jdk1.6.0_23* and I'm getting the following Java error:

```
2011-02-10 16:25:50,951 [WrapperJarAppMain] WARN util.GrailsUtil - [WARNING] Property [ldapServerPort] of domain class com.collabnet.svnedge.console.Server has type [int] and doesn't support constraint [nullable]. This constraint will not be checked during validation.
2011-02-10 16:25:51,117 [WrapperJarAppMain] ERROR ehcache.Cache - Unable to set localhost. This prevents creation of a GUID. Cause was: vkqgae01: vkqgae01
java.net.UnknownHostException: vkqgae01: vkqgae01
at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1354)
at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.<clinit>(Cache.java:143)
```

My server has 3 NICs (`eth0`, `eth1` and `eth2`). I've added an entry to the hosts file bellow localhost containing the following:

```
127.0.0.1 vkqgae01
```

I can successfully `ping vkqgae01`, but `nslookup` cannot resolve it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably nslookup is not recognizing vkqgae01, because the resolv.conf file is pointing to real DNS server and querying it for that name.. It maybe be the problem..

Answer (score 56):

That is related with

> hostname

and

> /etc/hosts

If /etc/hosts doesn't containt the definition of the hostname it fails. Just add your hostname to /etc/host for example if your hostname is work add or modified the following line:

```
127.0.0.1   work        localhost
```

Comment: Thanks, this really did help me. My computer has a "user-friendly" name like `MyComputer.local` and it could not resolve that name when I was offline. Adding the record to `/etc/hosts` solved the problem.

Answer (score 12):

> I can succesfully ping vkqgae01, but nslookup cannot resolve it.
>
> Any ideas?

What happens?

- `vkqgae01` is resolved locally thanks to your hosts file.
- nslookup sends a query to your DNS, where `vkqgae01` is unknown.

**Suggestion:** add `vkqgae01` to hosts file of **every** machine where you "use" it.
Basically, the fact that the local hosts file on vkqgae01 contains `127.0.0.1 localhost vkqgae01` doesn't help other machines to solve its name.

Answer (score 4):

Just added the line below in /etc/hosts and it worked.

127.0.0.1       imac

Answer (score 2):

nslookup queries DNS specifically and directly. This means it will *not* be able to show anything added directly to an /etc/hosts file (as that isn't DNS).
If you want to properly make sure your system will resolve a name, use getent:
'getent hosts vkqgae01'

Answer (score -2):

You need to restart the container if */etc/hosts* was changed as far as JVM caches local addresses/names on the first `InetAddress` call. It looks like `InetAddress` implementation bug, but still not fixed.