# JBOSS Unknowhost exception

Tags: java, jboss, centos

While starting the JBOSS Application server, i'm getting the exception

```
2014-03-26 13:14:01.104 INFO  [NamingService] JNDI bootstrap JNP=/0.0.0.0:1089, RMI=/0.0.0.0:1088, backlog=50, no client SocketFactory, Server SocketFactory=class org.jboss.net.sockets.DefaultSocketFactory
2014-03-26 13:14:01.969 WARN  [ServiceController] Problem starting service jboss:service=invoker,type=http
java.net.UnknownHostException: myserver2: myserver2
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1354)
    at org.jboss.invocation.http.server.HttpInvoker.checkInvokerURL(HttpInvoker.java:204)
    at org.jboss.invocation.http.server.HttpInvoker.startService(HttpInvoker.java:101)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
```

The JBOSS version is 4.04GA. I have started the JBOSS using ./run.sh.

The application server is hosted in CENTOS[Linux]:

I have already tried these solutions, but it's never working. 
[java.net.UnknownHostException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969156/error-java-net-unknownhostexception)

Can anyone help on this case.?

MY /etc/hosts/ file looks:

```
127.0.0.1 myserver2 localhost myserver2
::1 localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6 myserver2
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 myserver2
```

Thanks in advance,

Anyone can reply.. Help needed..

Comment: myserver2 can't be resolved.  Does it need to be in /etc/hosts?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I couldn't get your point?

Comment: Hi Geoff Wulliams. we have solved by adding this to the HOST file in other server and it worked. but not working in this server. both are same config

Comment: i solved it myself. tks

Comment: share with us how did you solve it ?!!

Comment: Sorry. It's been 5 years. I forgot.